# What does ``kubectl set env daemonset aws-node` mean?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

This page: https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/blob/master/docs/iam-policy.md

uses:
`kubectl set env daemonset aws-node -n kube-system CLUSTER_NAME=${YourClusterName}`

and according to this page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/

everything after `set` seems to be a subcommand.

However, I don't understand what subcommand this is: `daemonset aws-node -n kube-system CLUSTER_NAME=${YourClusterName}`

Can someone explain (hopefully with more docs)?

Comment: ref doc here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-env-em-

Answer (score 0):

`...don't understand what subcommand this is: daemonset aws-node -n kube-system CLUSTER_NAME=${YourClusterName}`

Every EKS node runs an instance of aws-node pod which provide CNI functionality to the node. The command set the environment variable named `CLUSTER_NAME` value to the name of your cluster for every pod managed by the daemonset. So that you do not need to go node by node to change each running pod environment variable, the command set and automatically restart all the pod(s) for you.

Comment: Buried, several hundred pages down, in the attached document above is: `Usage
$ kubectl set env RESOURCE/NAME KEY_1=VAL_1 ... KEY_N=VAL_N`. Is daemonset the RESOURCE? If so, why is there no `/`?

Comment: In this case `daemonset` is the resource. Use of daemonset/aws-node` vs `daemonset aws-node` are the same.